# Improve readability in my CLI application's hash returns using map or each

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, each

My application returns a hash of keys and values and I'd like it to display them in an easily readable way.  Is there a way I can get it to display the key's as well as the info.  So if I search for a strain it will return something similar to this

ID: The ID number
Name: The name
Race: The race
flavor: the flavor
etc.

sample of what it prints:

````
Choosing ALL returns a LOT of data, be ready for it!
By what strain attribute would you like to search? Flavor
Which Flavor would you like to search for? If nothing is returned, your search term isn't one thats accepted. coffee
strainer.rb:21: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
{"id"=>156, "name"=>"Bhang Chocolope", "race"=>"sativa", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>262, "name"=>"Black '84", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>353, "name"=>"Blue Ox", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>369, "name"=>"Blue Zombie", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>478, "name"=>"Caramel Candy Kush", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}      
{"id"=>479, "name"=>"Caramel Kona Coffee Kush", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>480, "name"=>"Caramelicious", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>502, "name"=>"Cheeseburger", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>549, "name"=>"Chocolate Kush", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>555, "name"=>"Chocolope", "race"=>"sativa", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>641, "name"=>"Dakini  Kush", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>897, "name"=>"Gorilla Biscuit", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1008, "name"=>"Head Trip", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1112, "name"=>"Jesse's Girl", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1149, "name"=>"Karma Bitch", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1153, "name"=>"Kelly Hill Gold", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1196, "name"=>"LA Chocolat", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1199, "name"=>"LA Kookies", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1225, "name"=>"Lee Roy", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1274, "name"=>"Logic Diesel", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1296, "name"=>"Madman OG", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1593, "name"=>"Pre-98 Bubba Kush", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1745, "name"=>"Royal Highness", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1762, "name"=>"Sasquatch Sap", "race"=>"hybrid", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1876, "name"=>"Super Cat Piss", "race"=>"sativa", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>1970, "name"=>"The OX", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}
{"id"=>2022, "name"=>"Truffle Butter", "race"=>"indica", "flavor"=>"Coffee"}```

This is what I have so far: 

```ruby
selection = AttributeParser.new("http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/rvxnT8j/strains/search/#{first_choice}/#{encoded_second_choice}")

results = selection.parse_json

puts results.map {|x| x.values}.uniq
````

what I've tried and its results

````
Choosing ALL returns a LOT of data, be ready for it!
By what strain attribute would you like to search? Flavor
Which Flavor would you like to search for? If nothing is returned, your search term isn't one thats accepted. coffee
strainer.rb:21: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
156
Bhang Chocolope
sativa
Coffee
262
Black '84      
indica
Coffee
353
Blue Ox        
indica
Coffee
369
Blue Zombie    
indica
Coffee
478
Caramel Candy Kush
hybrid
Coffee
479
Caramel Kona Coffee Kush
indica
Coffee
480
Caramelicious
hybrid
Coffee
502
Cheeseburger
hybrid
Coffee
549
Chocolate Kush
indica
Coffee
555
Chocolope
sativa
Coffee
641
Dakini  Kush
indica
Coffee
897
Gorilla Biscuit
indica
Coffee
1008
Head Trip
hybrid
Coffee
1112
Jesse's Girl
indica
Coffee
1149
Karma Bitch
hybrid
Coffee
1153
Kelly Hill Gold
indica
Coffee
1196
LA Chocolat
hybrid
Coffee
1199
LA Kookies
hybrid
Coffee
1225
Lee Roy
indica
Coffee
1274
Logic Diesel
hybrid
Coffee
1296
Madman OG
hybrid
Coffee
1593
Pre-98 Bubba Kush
indica
Coffee
1745
Royal Highness
hybrid
Coffee
1762
Sasquatch Sap
hybrid
Coffee
1876
Super Cat Piss
sativa
Coffee
1970
The OX
indica
Coffee
2022
Truffle Butter
indica
Coffee
[20:09:17]  strainer (master)```
````

Comment: Can you show an example of what it currently prints? We don't really know the data format.

Comment: I updated the post with a sample of what it returns if you choose flavor for the first search term and then coffee.

Comment: The app's returning an array of hashes, but you would like to display something more user-friendly, right? Is there a reason the app can't return an array of user-friendly strings?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The reason at the moment is I'm brain farting on how to do it 

Comment: I've been close using map but it comes out cleaner and not in a hash but not really easier to read because then it became a single column of info

Comment: And I'd like it to display the keys as well but like Name: Bhang Chocolope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great console library called [Hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) which can be used just for this purpose.
For example, assuming your array of hashes is in `data`, we can do this:

```
require 'hirb'
puts Hirb::Helpers::AutoTable.render(data, fields: %w|id name flavor race|)
```

Result:

```
+-----+--------------------------+--------+--------+
| id  | name                     | flavor | race   |
+-----+--------------------------+--------+--------+
| 156 | Bhang Chocolope          | Coffee | sativa |
| 262 | Black '84                | Coffee | indica |
| 353 | Blue Ox                  | Coffee | indica |
| 369 | Blue Zombie              | Coffee | indica |
| 478 | Caramel Candy Kush       | Coffee | hybrid |
| 479 | Caramel Kona Coffee Kush | Coffee | indica |
| 480 | Caramelicious            | Coffee | hybrid |
| 502 | Cheeseburger             | Coffee | hybrid |
| 549 | Chocolate Kush           | Coffee | indica |
| 555 | Chocolope                | Coffee | sativa |
| 641 | Dakini  Kush             | Coffee | indica |
| 897 | Gorilla Biscuit          | Coffee | indica |
| ... | ...                      | ...    | ...    |
+-----+--------------------------+--------+--------+
```